# Does the Master git branch need to be explicitly created or committed to for it to exist?

Tags: git

I initialised a git repo from existing code and immediately created a new branch. After some work I needed to revert back to the original state (which I assumed would simply be by running '`git checkout master`') however, this didn't work. When I run `git branch`, the only branch listed is the newly created branch and not the original 'master'. As I write this I realise I can simply do a revert to get to my original state. However, my question still stands: Do I have to either commit or explicitly define the master branch?

Comment: How did you create the repo and branch?  Which git commands?  I ask because, normally, the master branch is created for you.

Comment: @PaulHicks that was my assumption too. But I think the fact that I didn't do an initial commit right after running 'git init' is what messed me up since there is no commit against my 'master' repo.

Answer (score 3):

The master branch is created when you do your first commit after `git init`.
You could create the master branch to start from your first commit on your branch.

```
git branch master <commit>
```

Where you look up the commit id from the last line of

```
git log --oneline
```